# Android: Button action not being called

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to make an app where you start at a menu, click a button and are brought to a list of items (which I later hope to make clickable). But I can't seem to make it call my next activity. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

**Your main class / activity:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
setContentView(R.layout.main);

// Menu Button
Button startNewActivity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startnew);
startNewActivity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent newActivityIntent = new Intent(YOUR-CLASS-NAME.this,NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(newActivityIntent);
    }
});
```

**Your NewActivity Class:**

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton you guys are fast and few helpful. Seems my problems was i was using ListActivity instead of Activity. I changed that and it worked great. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Is the question "How do I call the next activity" ?

If so, it's pretty easy - Assuming the Activity you want to call is "SomeActivity", call this:

```
Intent someActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SomeActivity.class);
startActivity(someActivity);
```

There's also a "startActivityForResult" method, if you want data back from the Activity you're calling.  For reference, the Activity page of the API Documentation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).  Good luck!